# Pipes, child processes, and the scope of a child process

Tags: c, unix, concurrency, pipe, fork

I am in an Operating Systems class and I have a project that deals with forks and pipes. I'm trying to understand forks and pipes a little better before I get started on my project, so I was working through an example. This is the code in question (case 0 for when pid=fork() is equal to 0 and is a child process):

```
switch(pid = fork())
```

{

```
case -1:

  perror("fork call");
  exit(2);
  break;
case 0:
  char str1[MSGSIZE]; 
  char str2[MSGSIZE]; 
  char str3[MSGSIZE];
  printf("Enter a string! ");
  fgets(str1, MSGSIZE, stdin);
  printf("Enter another string! ");
  fgets(str2, MSGSIZE, stdin);

  printf("Enter the last string! ");
  fgets(str3, MSGSIZE, stdin);


  close(p[0]);
  write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], msg2, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], msg3, MSGSIZE);
  printf("About to write str1,str2,str3...\n");
  write(p[1], str1, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], str2, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], str3, MSGSIZE);
  break;
default:
  close(p[1]);
  for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
  {
    read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE);
    printf("%s\n", inbuf);
  }
  wait(NULL);   

  }//switch
```

When I compile on the command line I get these errors:

$ gcc -o p3 pipe3.c

pipe3.c:45:7: error: expected expression
      char str1[MSGSIZE]; 
      ^

pipe3.c:49:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'str1'
      fgets(str1, MSGSIZE, stdin);
            ^

pipe3.c:62:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'str1'
      write(p[1], str1, MSGSIZE);
                  ^

3 errors generated.

I initially declared str1, str2, and str3 at the beginning of the main function (where I know this is still the parent process at this point) and didn't get these errors when I compiled. The only reason I attempted to declare these in the child process was because I was trying to understand the scope of a child process and what it was capable of, meaning I'm just trying to experiment and wrap my head around what is legal and illegal. I don't really understand why the compiler cares that the child process is the one creating and initializing the variables and then only using them in the scope of the child process to write to the pipe. So I guess the main question I'm trying to ask is, is this in fact a limitation of a pipe? I tried using char *str1; in the child process and then storing the input using fgets as well, but I still get the same compiler error. Also, am I wrong in thinking that the scope of a child process is only the code that is in between case 0: and break; or does the child process get an entire copy of the parent program in the sense that the rest of the code in the parent process is ignored because the only time the child process executes code is when pid == 0? I know this is probably somewhat fundamental stuff, but Operating Systems is the first class that has had me thoroughly stumped as a programmer.

Here is my entire source code for context and completeness:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char inbuf[MSGSIZE];
  char *msg1 = "Hello world #1";
  char *msg2 = "Hello world #2";
  char *msg3 = "Hello world #3";
  char str1[MSGSIZE]; 
  char str2[MSGSIZE]; 
  char str3[MSGSIZE];

  int  p[2], j;
  pid_t pid;    

  if(pipe(p) == -1)
  {
    perror("pipe call");
    exit(1);
  }

  switch(pid = fork())
  {

case -1:

  perror("fork call");
  exit(2);
  break;
case 0:
  //char *str1; 
  //char *str2; 
  //char *str3;
  printf("Enter a string! ");
  fgets(str1, MSGSIZE, stdin);
  printf("Enter another string! ");
  fgets(str2, MSGSIZE, stdin);

  printf("Enter the last string! ");
  fgets(str3, MSGSIZE, stdin);


  close(p[0]);
  write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], msg2, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], msg3, MSGSIZE);
  printf("About to write the input strings...\n");
  write(p[1], str1, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], str2, MSGSIZE);
  write(p[1], str3, MSGSIZE);
  break;
default:
  close(p[1]);
  for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
  {
    read(p[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE);
    printf("%s\n", inbuf);
  }
  wait(NULL);   

  }//switch

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C (before C99) needs variables to be declared at the beginning of a bloc. A function (including `main`) is a bloc in that sense.

The `switch` could be a block, but a `case` is not, so you cannot declare new variables in a case. The *real* error is at `char str1[MSGSIZE];` which is not accepted by the compiler, and as such `str1` is not declared what causes the 2 other errors.

If you want to declare the variables only in the child (what has sense for you as a programmer, but not for the compiler : `fork` is just a function for it) you can do it in two way :

- a clean one would be to put that in a function and call the function :

  ```
  void doCopy(int *p) {
    char str1[MSGSIZE]; 
    char str2[MSGSIZE]; 
    char str3[MSGSIZE];
    printf("Enter a string! ");
    fgets(str1, MSGSIZE, stdin);
    printf("Enter another string! ");
    fgets(str2, MSGSIZE, stdin);

    printf("Enter the last string! ");
    fgets(str3, MSGSIZE, stdin);


    close(p[0]);
    write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE);
    write(p[1], msg2, MSGSIZE);
    write(p[1], msg3, MSGSIZE);
    printf("About to write the input strings...\n");
    write(p[1], str1, MSGSIZE);
    write(p[1], str2, MSGSIZE);
    write(p[1], str3, MSGSIZE);
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  ...
          case 0:
              doCopy(p, MSGSIZE);
              break;
  ...
  ```
- a less idiomatic but compilable way would be to force the creation of the bloc with a *dummy* if :

  ```
  ...
    switch(pid = fork())
    {

  case -1:

    perror("fork call");
    exit(2);
    break;
  case 0:
    if(1) {
        char str1[MSGSIZE]; 
        char str2[MSGSIZE]; 
        char str3[MSGSIZE];
        printf("Enter a string! ");
        fgets(str1, MSGSIZE, stdin);
        printf("Enter another string! ");
        fgets(str2, MSGSIZE, stdin);

        printf("Enter the last string! ");
        fgets(str3, MSGSIZE, stdin);


        close(p[0]);
        write(p[1], msg1, MSGSIZE);
        write(p[1], msg2, MSGSIZE);
        write(p[1], msg3, MSGSIZE);
        printf("About to write the input strings...\n");
        write(p[1], str1, MSGSIZE);
        write(p[1], str2, MSGSIZE);
        write(p[1], str3, MSGSIZE);
    }
    break;
  default:
  ...
  ```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help! That makes a lot of sense. I tried pushing the code in case 0 into its own scope and that worked. The function is definitely a better way to go about too.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no idea about processes. It only cares about braces. You are getting the errors because you are in a c89 mode, where variables must be declared at the beginning of the scope (notice that `case` does *not* open a scope).

Try to make the entire contents of `case 0` into a block, or pass `-std=c99` option to the compiler.

Comment: Oh wow, I never realized that. I was beginning to think I missed something major about forks or processes haha. Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help!